# on his first slice

Tags: usage

Example:
Jeff and Jack are sharing a pizza. Jeff **is on** his first slice while Jack **is on** his second.

Is 'is on' correct to mean 'is eating' in this context? Is it perfectly natural use or unusual?

Comment: **on** is like an index into an array and its practical meaning is derived from context.   *The difficult children were on their fourth nanny in as many months*  vs *The movie star was on her third husband*  vs *The competitive eater was on his 24th sausage.*  As Astralbee says, it's "generic".

Comment: You are either interested in the idiom or not. The idiom = to be + on [a/the noun] and replaces using a verb. I am on my second explanation of this. Aren't you interested?

Answer (score 3):

'On' doesn't specifically mean 'eating' - in this context it is a more generic term denoting where one is up to in something they are progressing with. For example:

- I'm on page 42 of my new book
- I'm on the second level of my game

It is perfectly natural in the context of your example, eating pizza slices.

Comment: Here, to be on a first or second slice of pizza does mean eating, specifically.

Comment: @Lambie No that's not correct. If I had eaten 2 slices, got the 3rd on my plate but was having a little rest before beginning, I would still say that I was on my third slice. So "on" should definitely not be read as "eating". To tell an English learner otherwise would be confusing.

Comment: Well, I would not say I was on my third slice if I was not engaged in eating it. I'd say, I'm having a  little rest but will be on my third slice soon. It's funny to me that you are ignoring the to be on + noun as an idiom. Where to be on replaces a verb, often an action verb.,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **to be on a first, second etc. slice of pizza** is correct. In this context, the idiom means: **to be eating.** or To be about to eat, to be finicky.

It is also correct for a **number of food/drink items**:

I am **on my third Martini**.
He is **on his 4th pancake**.
He's **on his second ice-cream**.

Also, **it can be used in non-food contexts:**

For example:
He's **on his third TV series** in three days. [watching a tv series]
They are **on their second book** for the program. [reading a book]
We are **on our fifth song**. [play or compose a song]

Basically, to be on [ordinal number + noun] replaces the active verb you might otherwise use:

That couple is **on their third child**. [having children]
He's **on his fifth try**. [trying to accomplish something]

Comment: How can you say that it's an "idiom" for eating and then your first example is a drink?

Comment: @Astralbee pancakes and ice cream are food.  And I said in black and white: food and drink items.

Comment: But you don't 'eat' a drink. Your answer is confusing, given the question. The OP has directly asked if it means eating... it doesn't exclusively mean that at all, yet you've said it's an idiom and that it means exactly that!

Comment: @Astralbee No, it isn't. **First**, I say yes, it means eating a slice a pizza. **Then, I say it is an idiom and explain it**. **Finally**, I say it can be used for food and drink items. How can that be confusing?

Comment: (As English learner, I find *In this context, the idiom means: to be eating.* clear enough to understand that, in the context of the question, *Jeff is on his first slice.* means *Jeff is eating his first slice of pizza.*)